# Single quote in OGC API Features request

Tags: qgis-server, encoding, url, request, ogc-api-features

Using a value containing a single quote character results in an empty feature array even there are features containing that value. [OCG WFS keyword-value pair encoding specification](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/04-094r1/04-094r1.html#98) talks about URL encoding and it works fine for every other kind of requests. Is this a bug or do I need a different encoding for this character?

The used value is `Centre d'Interpretació` and my URL is encoded as `Centre%20d%27Interpretaci%C3%B3`, the whole URL request using QGIS Server does look like this:

```
https://map.example.com/qgisserver/wfs3/collections/pois/items.geojson?type=Centre%20d%27Interpretaci%C3%B3
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: WFS returns the items when asking for all of them, but doesn't if I filter them adding a parameter like `?type=Centre d'Interpretació` which contains a single quote.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct type name

Comment: Yes, values without a single quote like `?type=Mirador` just work fine.

Comment: But are you sure that that is the name as known to the server?

Comment: Yes, that name does show up exactly like that (as value for field type) in case I do request all WFS features.

Comment: Your URL doesn't appear to be a WFS request so referencing WFS 1.1.0 documentation probably won't be helpful   WFS3 is a deprecated name for OGC API features (not WFS)  the correct documentation would be found at https://ogcapi.ogc.org/features/

Comment: That's right, I linked the wrong documentation. For now I changed the values, after removing single quotes everything works fine.